# Change button background colour on tap in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

I am trying to change colour of my `Button` in SwiftUI.
This is my whole CustomButton view struct:

```
struct CustomButton: View {

    @State private var didTap:Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.didTap = true
        }) {

        Text("My custom button")
            .font(.system(size: 24))
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 75, alignment: .center)
        .padding(.all, 20)
        .background(Color.yellow)

        //My code above this comment works fine

        //I tried something like this, but it is not working
     //   if didTap == true {
     //   .background(Color.blue)
     //    }

    }
}
```

This is what my button looks like (which is fine):

[image: My custom button]

But my question is: **how can I change the background colour when user taps this button.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For doinng this you need to give the colour as per the state changed:

```
struct CustomButton: View {

@State private var didTap:Bool = false

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        self.didTap = true
    }) {

    Text("My custom button")
        .font(.system(size: 24))
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 75, alignment: .center)
    .padding(.all, 20)
    .background(didTap ? Color.blue : Color.yellow)
  }
}
```

**PS:** If you want to manage other states too then you can go for the `enum`.

Comment: Is there any way to reset the color back after a tap?

Comment: @pizzae instead of doing `self.didTap = true` use `self.didTap.toggle()` and then it will switch back and forth on each tap.

Comment: @jwknz Does that mean you have to tap it again, i.e. a total of 2 times to get to the original color? Is there a way to make it so that it changes color back instantly after a single tap?

Comment: @pizzae Well it won’t change back to the original color unless you set that color to be the value of false - so then yes that would be 2 taps. If you want it to change back after a period of time then you can use timer and set it back after a number of seconds or whatever it is you want it to achieve.

Answer (score 7):

Just in case somebody wanted different way of doing this. 
It works for more colors.

```
struct CustomButton: View {

    @State private var buttonBackColor:Color = .yellow

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {

            //This changes colors to three different colors.
            //Just in case you wanted more than two colors.
             if (self.buttonBackColor == .yellow) {
                 self.buttonBackColor = .blue
             } else if self.buttonBackColor == .blue {
                 self.buttonBackColor = .green
             } else {
                 self.buttonBackColor = .yellow
             }

            //Same code using switch
            /*
             switch self.buttonBackColor {
             case .yellow:
                 self.buttonBackColor = .blue
             case .blue:
                 self.buttonBackColor = .green
             default:
                 self.buttonBackColor = .yellow
             }
             */
        }) {

        Text("My custom button")
            .font(.system(size: 24))
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 75, alignment: .center)
        .padding(.all, 20)
        .background(buttonBackColor)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But in the new Ways, or in the new version of Swift, Xcode, and iOS, you just have to write `.color_name`, if you will use class, like above, then it will generate errors.

In the Struct class just add in the `ContentView: View`:

```
@State private var didTap:Bool = false

Button(action:{
    self.didTap = true
}) {
    Text("ಕನ್ನಡ").font(.system(size: 17))
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .foregroundColor(didTap ? .orange :.black)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth:143)
        .padding()
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(Color.white)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 0, y: 2)
        )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did this a while ago based on a quiz making app. If the user got an answer correct, it would turn a button green, if wrong, turns the button red. The same could work for just a clickable button as well by removing the elif statement.

```
    @IBAction func answerButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    
    let actualAnswer = quiz[questionNumber].a
    let buttonPressed = sender.currentTitle!

    
    if buttonPressed == actualAnswer {
        print("Right")
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    } else {
        print("wrong")
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
```